# How does targeting work in the console versions?

Tags: version-differences, manhunt

The PC version seems to lack a designated "target" (lock-on) key (see [controls](http://www.projectmanhunt.com/manhunt/play_mechanics.php#playstation2controls)), targeting is performed by holding the light or strong attack key instead. Unfortunately this control scheme results in accidental attack moves — in Manhunt even melee swings make a sound and a great deal of stealth takedowns have failed when it's not clear if I'm close enough to an enemy to target, at worst hitting him.
[Executions](http://www.projectmanhunt.com/manhunt/play_mechanics.php#executions) are extremely important and direct melee confrontations are seen as the last resort (also negatively affects the player's score). Enemies can be executed with a single key press (takes longer if you want to achieve a high [end-level rating](http://www.projectmanhunt.com/manhunt/play_mechanics.php#scenerating)) when approached silently, but take dozens of hits in face-to-face brawls and nearby units are alerted.

How does targeting work in the console versions? Is it possible to perform a basic attack when targeting an enemy or are only execution moves accepted in this phase?

Comment: I have discovered that the character raises his arm when he is able to perform a takedown, so far all attempts have been successful. This was also noted in some in-game tutorial screen.

Answer (score -3):

I played manhunt 2 on PS2 a long time ago, and if I remember correctly I was using the right stick (pressing the right stick) t target. Try anyway. By the way marking you can make any attack

Comment: The original Manhunt, I would have used `manhunt-2` tag otherwise.

Comment: I don't use a controller, Manhunt was released before Windows' [XInput API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectInput#XInput) and and won't fully support modern gamepads.